# Access nested object using suiteScript in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have added a custom field in department, namely "Symbol", and I am trying to access it from CurrentRecord (of tepy Fixed Asset) using suite script.

The current record is a fixed asset and whenever I use .getValue(), it returns departments ID and whenever I use getText() it returns Department title.

However, I need to get Department object so that I can access its custom text field I have created. That is, "Symbol" field.

How can I do that? What is the correct path?

Code

```
CurrentRecord.get().getValue({fieldId: 'custrecord_assetdepartment' });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the department's `internalid`, you'll need to do a lookup;

```
 var fieldLookup = search.lookupFields({
    type: search.Type.DEPARTMENT,
    id: departmentId,
    columns: 'custrecord_assetdepartment'
});
var asset = fieldLookup['custrecord_assetdepartment'];
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, How about getting the same thing but from a fixed asset hype?

Comment: Fixed assets have a record type of `customrecord_ncfar_asset`. I'd suggest the [NetSuite Field Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-field-explorer/cekalaapeajnlhphgdpmngmollojdfnd) extension, it'll help you find record types and field values.